# Count specific assets (one column) which belongs to unique users (depending on another column)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

To get the total of In Stock. I used this formula and it works. but this formula works for specific text.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="In Stock")*(B2:B6="Laptop"))
```

I need simpler formula to count rest user's asset count except "In Stock"

example file:

[image]

Comment: A slimier formula? `Floor` should be pretty slimy..

Answer (score 0):

Put this in E2 and copy down it references the value in F2 as the one to count:

```
=CountIfs(A:A,"<>In Stock",B:B,F2)
```

Comment: It not working.